# How to get threads->tid() value in XS code?

Tags: perl, xs

I need to get current perl thread id in a C function inside *.XS part of a perl module.

In pure perl (*.pm part) I would simply do:

```
$id = threads->tid();
```

But what is a recommended way to get this value in XS?

Unfortunately http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html do not talk about dealing with threads in XS.

Thanks in advance

--
kmx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a method, one uses [`call_method`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html).

```
 UV get_tid() {
    dSP;
    UV tid;

    ENTER;
    SAVETMPS;

    PUSHMARK(SP);
    XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSVpv("threads", 0)));
    PUTBACK;

    count = call_method("tid", G_SCALAR|G_EVAL);

    SPAGAIN;
    if (SvTRUE(ERRSV) || count != 1)
        tid = 0;
    else
        tid = (UV)POPi;
    PUTBACK;

    FREETMPS;
    LEAVE;

    return tid;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but only in case when my module is loaded (by "use MyModule") together with "use threads". How to detect in XS that threads were not loaded (thus tid=0)? Now your code thows an error like: Can't locate object method "tid" via package "threads" at ...

Comment: I have got it, I need G_SCALAR|G_EVAL

Comment: There should also be a #ifndef USE_ITHREADS tid = 0 and optionally a module importer via Perl_load_module().

Comment: Let the .pm handle that.

Answer (score 0):

See how threads itself does it! I suggest you download `threads` from CPAN, unpack it and take a look at `threads.xs`. The part you need is a function called `ithread_tid`.

Comment: It returns threads' internal variable MY_CXT.context which I am afraid is not directly accessible from other modules